# C# +HTMLAgilityPack: retrive background-url value

Tags: c#, css, html-agility-pack

I'm going to extract background of some HTML files and replace them with new values. 
In order to control if **BODY** tag got background defined in its style as css i used below code:

```
foreach (HtmlNode bodyNode in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body"))
{
  if (bodyNode.Attributes.Contains("style") && bodyNode.Attributes["style"].Value.Replace(" ","").Contains("background-image:url"))
  {
    //code to replace background-url
  }

}
```

my problem is how to retrive background-url value from such tag from style properties:

```
<body style="background-image: url('test/bg.jpg')" >
```

and replace it with new value like below:

```
<body style="background-image: url('new value')" >
```

Comment: What about bodyNode.Attributes["style"].Value.Replace("background-image: url('test/bg.jpg')","background-image: url('new value')")?

Comment: first problem is there may be some other properties in style value other than background-image, the second is value inside url is not fixed think it like url(????) to url('something new')

Comment: bodyNode.Attributes["style"].Value.Replace(Regex.Match(bodyNode.Attributes["style"].Value, @"(?<=\().+?(?=\))").Value, "something new").Contains("background-image:url") ?

Comment: Regex.Match leads to object null reference!

Comment: What two string led to object null reference?

Comment: i think there may be something with REGEX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code below. 
Extract background-image url (string between brackets) with regex and replace it with new image.
Now remove style attribute and add new (style with replaced image).

This will work with all properties values and formats.

```
           foreach (HtmlNode bodyNode in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body"))
            {
                string newImg = "new-value.png";
                if (bodyNode.Attributes.Contains("style") && bodyNode.Attributes["style"].Value.Contains("background-image:url"))
                {                     
                    string style = bodyNode.Attributes["style"].Value;
                    string oldImg = Regex.Match(style, @"(?<=\().+?(?=\))").Value;
                    string oldStyle = bodyNode.Attributes["style"].Value;
                    string newStyle = oldStyle.Replace(oldImg, newImg);

                    bodyNode.Attributes.Remove("style");
                    bodyNode.Attributes.Add("style", newStyle);
                }

            }
```

Comment: This will not get url("something.png") it only get the ones without quotes

Answer (score 1):

you can remove the old style and add the new style for example:

```
bodyNode.Attributes.Remove("style");
bodyNode.Attributes.Add("style", "width:95%;background-image: url('test/bg1.jpg');font-size:xx-large;text-align:center");
```

Comment: I want to change only background image and i dont want to remove/redefine other properties. meanwhile other properties have no predefined format and value.